# How can I increase the value in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I've wrote the following code

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst = [None] * 3
for i in range(0, 3):
    lst[i] = numbers[:]
```

So if I want to increase the value in first lst by 1 and increase the value in second lst my 2 and so on.
Can I solve this question by for loop?

Comment: What have you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:

```py
numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4]

lst = [None] *3

for i in range(0,3):
    lst[i] = [x+i+1 for x in numbers]
```

Here during each iteration we create new lists by adding i+1 to each value in the list, `numbers`.

For reference this approach is called [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehension.

```
numbers = [i+1+a for i,a in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Where `i` will be the index number(I added the +1 since it begins with 0), so for index 1 it will add 1, for index 2 it will add 2 and so on..

And `a` is the value held at the current index.

which will give an output of:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```